# macOS Catalina: Opening simultaneously multiple folders very slow (when compared to Mac OS X Leopard)

Tags: catalina, folders, leopard

In macOS Catalina, always in List View, when I select say 10 folders and press `ctrl-o` to open them, it takes approximately 10 seconds to open them all. Roughly 1 folder per second, whatever the folder and whatever its content. Closing them with `cmd-alt-w` is almost instantaneous though.

When I compare that to say Mac OS X Leopard, the same quantity of folders open (and close) almost instantaneously. I searched the web and found nothing regarding this matter. Any ideas on how to have on macOS Catalina a speed similar to the one of Mac OS X Leopard?

Comment: What hardware are you comparing?

Comment: & do they have comparable contents? just tested on 10 folders with varying contents, from a couple of docs to 2000 mixed items, inc apps, docs. installers & movies. I see a slight delay, <2s, then they all snap open at one time.

Comment: Are you using Icon View, or Column View?

Comment: @benwiggy always in List View (will update my initial post). Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @benwiggy I am comparing a MacBook Pro Intel Core 2 Duo running at 2.8 GHz, 4 GB RAM (MacBookPro5,2) and Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) with a MacBook Pro Quad-Core Intel Core i7 running at 2.8 GHz, 16 GBRAM (MacBookPro15,2) and macOS 10.15 Catalina. The former is super-fast opening the 10 folders almost instantaneously, whereas the latter the 10 folders take 10 seconds to open. I am under the impression that Apple force-delays the opening of folders. Perhaps by circumventing with a plist edit: https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/edit-property-lists-apda49a1bb2-577e-4721-8f25-ffc0836f6997/mac?

Comment: @Tetsujin I tested this "feature" with several new machines having macOS Catalina and all open folder at an approximate rate of 1 folder per second. Whatever the content.

Comment: Have you performed any other speed tests, like launching apps, or performing some other task? It may be that more is being done in Catalina for this particular task. 
If you're in List View, why do you want 10 new windows, when you can just do Command Right Arrow?

Comment: Did you check with Etrecheck? https://www.etrecheck.com

Comment: @benwiggy: because it is the way I work and I want to continue that way. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @howdytom: would you mind explaining/describing what this etrecheck does and how it might be helpful to accelerate the opening of several folders simultaneously?

Comment: @pdeli: EtreCheck will automatically alert you to serious problems like adware, insufficient RAM, or a failing hard drive which could be related to your question: https://etrecheck.com